# How to upgrade rails without test cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-upgrade

I'm going to upgrade rails from 4.0 to 4.1 and then 4.2.
However, the current system does not have any test cases.
And it is not easy and time consuming to write tests before the upgrade.

Is there anything I can do except following the [guideline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) to see what changes?

Comment: There is only two ways - write automated tests (MiniTest/Rspec) or test the whole app manually. You should decide, what is more time consuming for you, and how important is "don't have any bugs in production after upgrade"

Comment: +1 on @Vasilisa . Would highly recommend writing some tests before doing this as they will help with the upgrade and probably help you sleep easier at night. Then you also have tests for any further upgrades after this (or any new feature!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also doing an upgrade at the moment in my case a Rails 3.2 project which I will upgrade to Rails 5.2, through 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, 5.1. My project does not have a lot of tests so what I'm doing now is writing a lot of tests. Mainly Integration tests because there already are lots of unit tests fortunately.

If you want to be sure everything keeps working you really should add tests. Otherwise you will have to hunt for bugs for a long time after you upgraded your project. And you can't be sure where it goes wrong. In the end it will save you time.